# swift sprite kit - AVAudioPlayer not playing multiple sounds in same time simultaneously

Tags: ios, audio, swift, sprite, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to play sounds simultaneously but the player just cuts the sound without it finishing and starts playing the new sound, I want it to finish and not cut each time a new sound starts.

I have this right now:

```
let dropSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:NSBundle.mainbundle().
pathForResource("drop", ofType: "mp3")!)
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

and everytime I want to play a sound I do this

```
var error:NSError?
audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(ContentsOfUrl: dropSound, error: &error)
audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
audioPlayer.play()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a more efficient way, but you can try this for each sound. I tried it out with a couple sounds and it worked. If you don't want the your sounds to interrupt music that the user may be listening to, then just change `AVAdudioSessionCategoryPlayback` to `AVAdudioSessionCategoryAmbient`.

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

func playSound() {

var dropSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("drop", ofType: "mp3")!)

AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

var error: NSError?
audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: dropSound, error: &error)
audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
}

audioPlayer.play()
```

Comment: The problem is that when a new sound starts playing the sound before gets cut and doesn't finish playing

Comment: How are you triggering each sound to start?

Comment: Each time I want a sound to play I do playSoundOne() audioPlayer.play() I have multiple functions for different sounds

Comment: When I tested out the code I posted with 2 sounds, they didn't interrupt each other. To do that I had to make a completely different AudioPlayer variable and function for both. For what I'm doing a button action triggers the sound, so I put the yourPlayer.play() code in two different buttons.

Comment: Yea if you're using audioPlayer.play() for both sounds, I think that may be the problem. Try creating different ones for each sound and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't know you could have multiple players in the same time, thank you again!